# Partitioning a set to the maximum number of subsets summing to zero

Tags: algorithms, sets

Given a multiset of numbers $X = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$, such that $\sum X = 0$, how can $X$ be partitioned to the *maximum number* of subsets so that each subset sums to zero?

I have searched around a lot, but none of the partition or packing problem variants seem to address this particular case.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Looking for algorithms? Hardness proofs? References?

Comment: I'm looking for an algorithm, yes. I have an implementation of the [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) solution, which I can use to find some subsets, but I don't know how to continue from there on, or if i'm on the right track at all.

Answer (score 5):

3-Partition reduces to this problem, so it's strongly $NP$-hard. Moreover, 4-Partition also reduces to it (and the blowup is linear), so assuming the exponential time hypothesis there's no $2^{o(n)}$ algorithm.

Using dynamic programming there's a $O^*(4^n)$ algorithm, it would be interesting if you could do $2^n$ or even $1.99^n$.

Comment: Can you specify the algorithm?

Comment: @mgunyho [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339238/165143) is the actual reduction to the 3-partition problem I think :)